# Add trailing numbers to integers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

For example digits=4 means if input is 7 need output 7999, for 83 output should be 8399, for 9 output should be 9999. Want to add trailing 9 based on digits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take the stringes number and pad the needed values.

```js
function nines(value, digits) {
    return +value.toString().padEnd(digits, 9);
}

console.log(nines(83, 4));
```

A numerical version

```js
function nines(value, digits) {
    while (value < 10 ** (digits - 1)) value = value * 10 + 9;
    return value;
}

console.log(nines(83, 4));
console.log(nines(2, 1));
console.log(nines(2, 2));
```

Comment: Your Numerical solution work like charm. but what is ** meant inside while condition

Comment: it's the power of operator.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you may be able to do is to multiply the input number by a power of 10 in order to add extra digits of 0 to the end, and then use addition to add 9 into each of those newly created digits.

For example:

**Input - 7**

7 * 1000 -> 7000 *(NOTE: 1000 is a power of 10: 10^3)*

7000 + (100 * 9) + (10 * 9) + (1 * 9) = **7999**

**Input**

83 * 100 -> 8300 *(NOTE: 100 is a power of 10: 10^2)*

8300 + (10 * 9) + (1 * 9) = **8399**

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you want

```js
        trailNines(number) {
            let numberString = number.toString();
            let result = '';

            if(numberString.length === 4){
                result = number.toString();
            }

            if(numberString.length === 3) {
                result = number.toString() + '9';
            }

            if(numberString.length === 2) {
                result = number.toString() + '99';
            }

            if(numberString.length === 1) {
                result = number.toString() + '999';
            }

            return parseInt(result);
        }
```

Comment: but this is not a proper solution, suppose if have a number with 25 digits, do i need to add 25 if condition?